# Merge Redis set members values using a pattern

Tags: redis, zset

I have a simple `zset` named `pets`:

```
redis-cli zadd pets 1 cat1
redis-cli zadd pets 1 cat2
redis-cli zadd pets 1 cat3

redis-cli zadd pets 1 rat1
redis-cli zadd pets 1 rat2
```

The value is always `1`. Now the set state is `redis-cli zrange pets 0 -1 withscores`:

```
 1) "cat1"
 2) "1"
 3) "cat2"
 4) "1"
 5) "cat3"
 6) "1"
 7) "rat2"
 8) "1"
 9) "rat1"
10) "1"
```

Is there a way to merge set members based on a pattern? I want to sum all the members with the name starting with a prefix, in my case the pet type, so as to end up with the following:

```
1) "cat"
2) "3"
3) "rat"
4) "2"
```

I have tried [`zinterstore`](https://redis.io/commands/zinterstore) and [`zunionstore`](https://redis.io/commands/zunionstore) but they enforce having the same name for members of the sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there isn't a built-in Redis gimmick for that, but you could majik it with a Lua script (see the [`EVAL` command](https://redis.io/commands/eval)).

That said, if what you need is count of pet by prefix, you should consider an alternative data model that can serve that.

Comment: Agreed. I am letting go of prefixing by numbers and use `zincrby` instead. My only point was that a member of set should expire at a given point, but since it comes out expensive, I'll just expire the whole set at that point. Thanks!